# Is this secure enough?

Tags: php, security, pdo

I'm new with PDO, and I just wanted to know if this code:

```
$string = $_POST['string'];
$matches = $SQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?");
$matches->execute(array('%'.$string.'%'));

foreach($matches->fetchAll() as $match) {
    echo $match["name"]."<br/>";
}
```

Is secure enough? I just wan't to be sure and prevent from hacking.
This code will withdraw all `users` from the database with name like in the `$string` variable.

Feel free to post your solutions also!

Answer (score 4):

PDO will automatically escape any input given to it before executing the query, so in terms of an SQL injection attack, it is safe.